# What is the name of an algebraic structure between semi-group and group?

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

A group has an identity element and a an inverse element. A semi-group has neither. What is it called when a semi-group **does have an identity element but no inversion**?

The particular use-case is the "concatenation" operation on the set of all "strings" possible. Strings are a semi-group under concatenation:

- Closure: `concat(string1, string2)` is always another string
- Associativity: `concat(string1, concat(string2, string3))` = `concat(concat(string1, string2), string3)`

And even though there is no inversion, there does exist an identity element: the empty string (`""`).

- `concat(string1, "")` = `concat("", string1)` = `string1`

Comment: A monoid? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid - the 'string' case you mentioned is referenced right at the start

Comment: Yes monoid is now the standard term for this.

Comment: It says "unital semigroup", e.g. [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-021-02/S0002-9939-1969-0237378-0/S0002-9939-1969-0237378-0.pdf), Lemma 1, and the definition before it. But it is from $1968$.

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 thanks a lot! I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have to admit "unitary" or "unital" semigroup sounds much better than "monoid". Thanks!

Comment: @dietrich-burde The linked paper defines at the same time a notion of *left unital* semigroup, an asymetric notion which is apparently needed in the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only *monoid* is the standard term, but there is a [tag monoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monoid) on this site with 679 questions as of today.

The example you describe is the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on a set $A$, usually denoted by $A^*$, a frequently used object in theoretical computer science.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's called a **[monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid)**, and in some cases a **unitary or unital semi-group**. I have to admit the latter sounds more accurate even though it is less used. Thanks to everyone who commented the answer!